# Can I copy a widget from one Slate app to another?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

Is there a way to copy a widget that I have fully configured in one Slate app to another one? I would like to avoid having to recreate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your usual copy and paste commands on widgets. Just select them in the Canvas pane on the left in your Slate app, press Command + C, navigate to your second Slate app, press Command + V and the widget will appear.
Alternatively, you can also click on the three dots right next to your widgets name and select copy/cut to copy/cut the widget, but you will have to use Command/STRG + V to paste.

[image]

You will also get popups, indicating whether the copying and pasting was successful.

[image]

[image]